# How to insert and select global temporary table using jdbc oracle?

Tags: java, oracle

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO St (id) values ('Admin'); "  + 
            "select * from Student where id in (select id from St);";
```

Getting error if try to execute the above query

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:910)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1119)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
at com.prototype.service.DBConnection.main(DBConnection.java:167)
```

> Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 36, Sql = INSERT INTO St (id)
>   values ('Admin'); select * from Student where id in (select id from
>   St);, OriginalSql = INSERT INTO St (id) values ('Admin'); select *
>   from Student where id in (select id from St);, Error Msg = ORA-00933:
>   SQL command not properly ended

Comment: How did you enable the multi statement in your connection ?

Comment: there is extra `;` at the end. You need to remove

Comment: You can't send two statements at once, you need two calls, one for the insert and one for the query. (It isn't obvious why you want/need a GTT from your example though.)

Comment: I havn't enable allowMultiQueries in preparedStatement, and i have removed the semicolon(;) at the end still facing sane issue.

Comment: Its just an example though

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You have one complete correct insert statement and one complete correct select statement. One of them should be removed.

Comment: Note that this duplicate might be limited to mysql, I never had to really use it so only tried it for "fun".

Comment: Can we insert multiple queries into GTT without using stored procedure in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a insert select statement  and this way avoid multi statemenst query

```
String query = "INSERT INTO St (id) 
            select your_col_for_id  from Student where id in (select id from St);";
```

and you must be sure you have corresponding number and type of column in into clause and in select clause

Comment: I have achieved by using batch, I have added batch for insert query and executeBatch.